# notebook not installed with anaconda/jupyter

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I just installed Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64) for one of my course on MAC OS.

()Installation went OK

()PATH was updated

()ran the following commands and all seem to go OK.

```
conda update conda
conda update ipython
conda update pip
conda install bokeh
```

()version query returns

```
conda --version
conda 4.4.9
```

As per the instruction i should have notebook package installed.
But i get the following error

```
XXXXX@Admins-MacBook-Pro ~ $ jupyter notebook 
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

conda list only has ipython notebook

gsandhu@Admins-MacBook-Pro ~ $ conda list | grep notebook
ipython-notebook 2.2.0 py27_0

Previously i tried updating jupyter using "pip install jupyter" and i was able to start the notebook but then there were issues in kernal . So i uninstalled everything and started from fresh.

Can anyone please guide me through this? Thanks in Advance

Adding more details

After this if i do "pip install jupyter" . I can start notebook but right away i get the following error in in kernal .

```
File "/Users/gsandhu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in 
_run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/Users/gsandhu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/Users/gsandhu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
app.launch_new_instance()
File "/Users/gsandhu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)
File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
File "/Users/gsandhu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/gsandhu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 448, in initialize
self.init_sockets()
File "/Users/gsandhu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 251, in init_sockets
self.init_iopub(context)
File "/Users/gsandhu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 259, in init_iopub
self.iopub_thread = IOPubThread(self.iopub_socket, pipe=True)
File "/Users/gsandhu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/ipykernel/iostream.py", line 66, in __init__
self.io_loop = IOLoop(make_current=False)
File "/Users/gsandhu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/util.py", 
line 208, in __new__
instance.initialize(**args)
File "/Users/gsandhu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 133, in initialize
super(ZMQIOLoop, self).initialize(impl=impl, **kwargs)
TypeError: initialize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'make_current'
[W 22:57:04.292 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing `conda` you need to create an environment to work with, to do so head to Terminal and type

```
conda create -n environment_name python=3.6.3
```

Then after the environment has been created, you need to activate it using

```
source activate environment_name
```

Then you can perform installing Jupyter (with your environment activated)

```
conda install jupyter
```

To install other packages just do the same thing (with your environment activated) for example:

```
conda install numpy
conda install pandas
conda install scikit-learn
conda install matplotlib
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

To start using Jupyter, first you need to activate the environment, then you can type `jupyter notebook` to use it.

Comment: Thanks !  I see anaconda install creates a environment . checking "conda info --envs" i see the following
base                  *  /Users/XX/anaconda and i tried "source activate base" and then "conda install jupyter" . The OP gives error "PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:"

Comment: added some more details in the question

Comment: Yes. i tried "(base) "conda create -n myenv python=2.7.13" . But got the erro 
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - python=2.7.13" . After this i tried setting python=2.7,2 also. But same issue. After that i tried setting up up without python=XX option. I was able to create the env and issues activate cmd. Conda install jupyter agin failed as in the initial case.